# make three adjacent slanted divs

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a webpage for my project and I need three slanted divs next to each other. I found these two divs on codepen, but there are only two and I´d like to make one more div in middle, that is slant from both sides to fit in middle. I tried but can't figure it out. Can someone help me with this?

```css
/* build the rectangles */

.rr-left,
.rr-right {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  background: #2c3e50;
}

.rr-left {
  float: left;
  z-index: 8;
  width: 33%;
}

.rr-right {
  float: right;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 33%;
}


/* slanted edges using pseudo-elements */

.rr-left:after,
.rr-right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.rr-left:after {
  right: 0;
  border-left: 100px solid #2c3e50;
  /* razorblade color */
  border-bottom: 200px solid #FFFFFF;
  /* page background color */
}

.rr-right:before {
  left: -100px;
  border-right: 100px solid #2c3e50;
  /* razorblade color */
  border-top: 200px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  /* transparent */
}


/* hover styles */

.rr-left:hover,
.rr-right:hover {
  background: #34495e;
}

.rr-left:hover:after {
  border-left-color: #34495e;
}

.rr-right:hover:before {
  border-right-color: #34495e;
}


/* text positioning & styles */

.rr-text {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.rr-text h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.rr-text p {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rr-left">
  <div class="rr-text">
    <h3>rr-left div</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="rr-right">
  <div class="rr-text">
    <h3>rr-right div</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Responsive? Animated? The possibilities are endless; you've got to give concrete end-goal otherwise the answers to this are going to be almost purely subjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use display:flex. So you can set any width you want for the left and the right without worring about width of the center.

And I think it's more modern to use flex than float.

```css
/* build the rectangles */
container
{
  display:flex;
}

.rr-left,
.rr-right {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  background: #2c3e50;
}

.rr-left {
  z-index: 8;
  width: 33%;
}

.rr-right {
  z-index: 11;
  width: 33%;
}

.rr-mid
{
  flex:1;
  background-color:green;
  position:relative;
  z-index:10;
}

.rr-mid:before
{

  left: -100px;
border-right: 100px solid green;
border-top: 200px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
/* slanted edges using pseudo-elements */

.rr-left:after,
.rr-right:before,
.rr-mid:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.rr-left:after {
  right: 0;
  border-left: 100px solid #2c3e50;
  /* razorblade color */
  border-bottom: 200px solid #FFFFFF;
  /* page background color */
}

.rr-right:before {
  left: -100px;
  border-right: 100px solid #2c3e50;
  /* razorblade color */
  border-top: 200px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  /* transparent */
}


/* hover styles */

.rr-left:hover,
.rr-right:hover {
  background: #34495e;
}

.rr-left:hover:after {
  border-left-color: #34495e;
}

.rr-right:hover:before {
  border-right-color: #34495e;
}


/* text positioning & styles */

.rr-text {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.rr-text h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.rr-text p {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<container>
<div class="rr-left">
  <div class="rr-text">
    <h3>rr-left div</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="rr-mid">
  <div class="rr-text">
    <h3>rr-mid</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="rr-right">
  <div class="rr-text">
    <h3>rr-right div</h3>
  </div>
</div>
</container>
```

And with this method, if you don't say the width for left and right, they will take just the width for text.

Try to run the snippet in full page to see the difference.

```css
/* build the rectangles */
container
{
  display:flex;
}

.rr-left,
.rr-right {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  background: #2c3e50;
}

.rr-left {
  z-index: 8;
}

.rr-right {
  z-index: 11;
}

.rr-mid
{
  flex:1;
  background-color:green;
  position:relative;
  z-index:10;
}

.rr-mid:before
{

  left: -100px;
border-right: 100px solid green;
border-top: 200px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
/* slanted edges using pseudo-elements */

.rr-left:after,
.rr-right:before,
.rr-mid:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index:-1;
}

.rr-left:after {
  right: 0;
  border-left: 100px solid #2c3e50;
  /* razorblade color */
  border-bottom: 200px solid #FFFFFF;
  /* page background color */
}

.rr-right:before {
  left: -100px;
  border-right: 100px solid #2c3e50;
  /* razorblade color */
  border-top: 200px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  /* transparent */
}


/* hover styles */

.rr-left:hover,
.rr-right:hover {
  background: #34495e;
}

.rr-left:hover:after {
  border-left-color: #34495e;
}

.rr-right:hover:before {
  border-right-color: #34495e;
}


/* text positioning & styles */

.rr-text {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.rr-text h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.rr-text p {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<container>
<div class="rr-left">
  <div class="rr-text">
    <h3>rr-left div</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="rr-mid">
  <div class="rr-text">
    <h3>rr-mid</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="rr-right">
  <div class="rr-text">
    <h3>rr-right div</h3>
  </div>
</div>
</container>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that is actually responsive as each element is 33%.

Hope this help. I'll be around if you need anything else. :)

```css
/* build the rectangles */

.rr-left,
.rr-right,
.rr-middle {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  background: #2c3e50;
}

.rr-middle { 
background: aqua;
right: 33%;
}

.rr-left {
  float: left;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 33%;
}

.rr-right {
  float: right;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 33%;
  right: -33.5%;
}

.rr-middle {
  float: right;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 33%;
}


/* slanted edges using pseudo-elements */

.rr-left:after,
.rr-right:before,
.rr-middle:after,
.rr-middle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.rr-left:after {
  right: 0;
  border-left: 100px solid #2c3e50;
  /* razorblade color */
  border-bottom: 200px solid #FFFFFF;
  /* page background color */
}

.rr-right:before {
  left: -100px;
  border-right: 100px solid #2c3e50;
  /* razorblade color */
  border-top: 200px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  /* transparent */
}

.rr-middle:after {
  right: 0;
  border-left: 100px solid aqua;
  /* razorblade color */
  border-bottom: 200px solid #FFFFFF;
  /* page background color */
}

.rr-middle:before {
  left: -100px;
  border-right: 100px solid aqua;
  /* razorblade color */
  border-top: 200px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  /* transparent */
}




/* hover styles */

.rr-left:hover,
.rr-right:hover {
  background: #34495e;
}

.rr-left:hover:after {
  border-left-color: #34495e;
}

.rr-right:hover:before {
  border-right-color: #34495e;
}


/* text positioning & styles */

.rr-text {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.rr-text h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.rr-text p {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rr-left">
  <div class="rr-text">
    <h3>rr-left div</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="rr-middle">
  <div class="rr-text">
    <h3>rr-middle div</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="rr-right">
  <div class="rr-text">
    <h3>rr-right div</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this is the text is cut off at this width.  The inner div in the left floating element with the text should maybe have a maximum width so it isn't hiding behind the middle div, and the middle behind the right div.  But, this is almost exactly what I was about to submit as an answer.

Comment: @adpro i left out the text as it will all depend in the content.